# Can a smart contract deployed on a chain (ex: Ethereum) hold or store other layer 1 tokens?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Is it possible for a smart contract deployed on a chain (ex: Ethereum) to accept/receive and store other native tokens(ex: MATIC, BNB, etc) other than Ether?

For example, if I made a NFT marketplace contract, and deployed it to Ethereum, could I make it accept payment from buyers in a subset of other tokens?

This might be an obvious question but I haven't found a clear answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Developer advocate from Chainstack here

Yes and no.
The native token on Ethereum is only Ether, MATIC and BNB are the counterparts of Ether on Polygon and BSC. You won't be able to transfer them the same way as you transfer Ethers on Ethereum.

However, both BSC and Polygon have a wrapped version of their native token on Ethereum. You can make your marketplace work around these tokens:

- [BNB](https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52)
- [MATIC](https://etherscan.io/token/0x7d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb0)
- [BTC](https://etherscan.io/token/0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. In short, my marketplace can only receive ERC-20 tokens? Could I also store the proceeds on the marketplace like I could do with Ether? That way I could shift the risk associated with transferring the proceeds to the user(seller).

Comment: Hi Ade. If you limit your protocol to Ethereum then ERC-20 tokens are the only way. 
Based on your description, seems like you want to build a multichain NFT marketplace, where users can buy/sell NFTs across chains. Its complexity & risk are exponentially higher depending on the number of Chains involved but it is possible. You can build your own bridges to do that.